# What makes the Java linked-list implementation of a triple-ended queue slow?

Tags: java, linked-list, deque

I am solving Kattis problem Teque, and have to implement a teque (triple-ended queue) with just four operations: push to front, push to back, push to middle (median) and read item at index. The focus for this assignment is time complexity, so I've used a tailed linked list to easily add elements at the front and back.

For the push-to-middle function, instead of calling size() on my list, I stored a class variable in the Teque to keep track of the number of elements in the list. This enabled very quick lookup.

```
class Teque {
    public TailedLinkedList list;
    public Kattio io = new Kattio(System.in, System.out);
    public int numItems;

    public Teque() {
        this.list = new TailedLinkedList();
        this.numItems = 0;
    }

    public void push_back(int x) {
        numItems++;
        list.addBack(x);
    }

    public void push_front(int x) {
        numItems++;
        list.addFront(x);
    }

    public void push_middle(int x) {

        int median = (numItems + 1) / 2;
        list.addAtIndex(median, x);
        numItems++;
    }

    public int get(int i) {
        int result = list.getItemAtIndex(i);
        io.println(result);
        io.flush();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Implementation of TailedLinkedList:

```
import java.util.*;

class TailedLinkedList implements ListInterface {
    // attributes
    public ListNode head;
    public ListNode tail;
    public int num_nodes;

    // interface methods

    // Return true if list is empty; otherwise return false.
    public boolean isEmpty() { return (num_nodes == 0); }

    // Return number of items in list
    public int size() { return num_nodes; }

    // return index of item if item is found in the list, otherwise return -1
    public int indexOf(int item) {
        int index = 0;

        for (ListNode cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.getNext()) {
            if (cur.getItem() == item) 
                return index;
            else 
                index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    // return true if item is in the list false otherwise
    public boolean contains(int item) {
        if (indexOf(item) != -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // get item at index
    public int getItemAtIndex(int index) {
        int counter = 0;
        int item = 0;

        if (index < 0 || index > size()-1) {
            System.out.println("invalid index");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (index == size()-1)
            item = tail.getItem();
        else {
            for (ListNode cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.getNext()) {
                if (counter == index) {
                    item = cur.getItem();
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return item;
    }

    // Return first item
    public int getFirst() { return getItemAtIndex(0); }

    // Return last item
    public int getLast() { return getItemAtIndex(size()-1); }

    // add item at position index, shifting all current items from index onwards to the right by 1 
    // pre: 0 <= index <= size()
    public void  addAtIndex(int index, int item) {
        ListNode cur;
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(item);

        if (index >= 0 && index <= size()) {
            if (index == 0) // insert in front
                insert(null,newNode);
            else if (index == size()) // insert at the back, don't have to move all the way to the back
                insert(tail,newNode);
            else {
                cur = getNodeAtIndex(index-1); // access node at index-1
                insert(cur,newNode);
            }
        }
        else { // index out of bounds
            System.out.println("invalid index");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } 

    // Add item to front of list
    public void addFront(int item) { addAtIndex(0,item); }

    // Add item to back of list
    public void addBack(int item) { addAtIndex(size(),item); }

    // remove item at index and return it
    // pre: 0 <= index < size()
    public int removeAtIndex(int index) {
        ListNode cur;
        int item = 0;

        // index within bounds and list is not empty
        if (index >= 0 && index < size() && head != null) {
            if (index == 0) // remove 1st item
                item = remove(null);
            else {
                cur = getNodeAtIndex(index-1); // access node at index-1
                item = remove(cur);
            }
        }
        else { // index out of bounds
            System.out.println("invalid index or list is empty");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return item;
    }

    // Remove first node of list
    public int removeFront() { return removeAtIndex(0); }

    // Remove last node of list
    public int removeBack() { return removeAtIndex(size()-1); }

    // Print values of nodes in list.
    public void print() {
        if (head == null)
            System.out.println("Nothing to print...");
        else {
            ListNode cur = head;
            System.out.print("List is: " + cur.getItem());
            for (int i=1; i < num_nodes; i++) {
             cur = cur.getNext();
             System.out.print(", " + cur.getItem());
            }
            System.out.println(".");
        }
    }

    // non-interface helper methods
    public ListNode getHead() { return head; }
    public ListNode getTail() { return tail; }

    /* return the ListNode at index */
    public ListNode getNodeAtIndex(int index) {
        int counter = 0;
        ListNode node = null;

        if (index < 0 || index > size()-1) {
            System.out.println("invalid index");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (index == size()-1) // return tail if index == size()-1
            return tail;
        for (ListNode cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.getNext()) {
            if (counter == index) {
                node = cur;
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return node;
    }

    // insert newNode after the node referenced by cur 
    public void insert(ListNode cur, ListNode n) {
        // insert in front
        if (cur == null) {
            n.setNext(head);
            head = n; // update head
            if (tail == null) // update tail if list originally empty
                tail = head;
        }
        else { // insert anywhere else
            n.setNext(cur.getNext());
            cur.setNext(n);
            if (cur == tail) // update tail if inserted new last item
                tail = tail.getNext();
        }
        num_nodes++;
    }

    // remove the node referenced by cur.next, and return the item in the node 
    // if cur == null, remove the first node 
    public int remove(ListNode cur) {
        int value;

        if (cur == null) { // remove 1st node
            value = head.getItem();
            head = head.getNext(); // update head
            if (num_nodes == 1) // update tail to null if only item in list is removed
                tail = null;
        }
        else { // remove any other node
            value = cur.getNext().getItem();
            cur.setNext(cur.getNext().getNext());
            if (cur.getNext() == null) // update tail if last item is removed
                tail = cur;
        }
        num_nodes--;

        return value;
    }
}
```

However, the code I have still runs out of time (100k lines input, limit 2 seconds). Is there anywhere immediately obvious that I can improve on my algorithm? `addAtIndex` and `getItemAtIndex` run in O(n) time.

Comment: TailedLinkedList and test code are required here I think

Comment: TailedLinkedList is your implementantion or do you take from other place.  It is very hard to help you with the info that you provide

Comment: @Gatusko has been added in.

Comment: Why are you using a linked list for your queue? This will be slower than using an Array based collection.

Comment: I think you could implement a double linked list (i.e. links in two directions) yourself and keep references to head, tail and mid element. Whenever adding on either end you have to consider what happens with the middle reference. You will also have to clarify the requirements - if the list is `[A, B, C]` and you `push_middle(D)`, should you end with `[A, D, B, C]` or `[A, B, D, C]`?

Comment: @tramstheman insert at the front of array list is `O(n)`, while in case of linked list it's `O(1)`. On the other hand, access by index in case of array list is `O(1)`, while in case of linked list it's `O(n)`. The choice really depends on which of the four methods are called the most often.

@RyanChng What's your test input?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak That is true. The problem is you are only considering the academic time complexity. In real life we often have other bottlenecks. Contiguous data can be stored in a single page in the L1/L2/L3 cache. Linked lists have no guarantee that data is being stored contiguously, and in fact most of the time is not. This results in memory lookups which is hundreds of cpu cycles slower than the L1/L2/L3 cache.

Comment: @moonboy you are right, but memory/OS/cache optimisations will not make the array list faster than linked list when adding at the front. In this case, I cannot see a way to make all methods fast, at least one of them will be slow. OP's problem might be that a few of his methods are slow - `get` and `push_middle` both have to iterate over the list and this can be avoided (for one method only).

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I wasn't claiming that an array based collection would have better performance at inserting to the front. My claim is that overall performance is going to be better. Obviously, to your point, what matters most is going to be how frequently insertions are called. However, considering this is just a queue implementation at its core, different strategies utilizing an array can be used which would optimize performance.

Comment: It's random. I won't know how many push_middles vs gets I have.

Comment: @RyanChng Then I suggest that you delete your `TailedLinkedList` and use an `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: @RyanChng You have mentioned in one of the comments to some answer that you have performance tests for this task. Can you please provide them in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the test cases they're giving us are all private. This does make it really frustrating, but I can only presume there are a distributed number of calls to get and push_middle across all the cases. If it helps, this is Kattis problem Teque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push_midle` is causing walking through half of the list. A solution would be to use **two lists**, the first half and the second half. Should the lists get unbalanced, shift elements between both lists.

(It just might be that a ListIterator might do too; though one must fear a ConcurrentModificationException for a naive approach.)

Comment: Won't the shifting of elements between lists add to the time complexity?

Comment: Half of the adds/removes front and back would effect a push_middle and vice versa. So no. However `get` by index is another cause for losing speed.

Comment: Hmm. I tried your implementation but ended up with a worse runtime somehow.

Comment: I searched for `TailedLinkedList`, and the one I found was not a double linked list as java's LinkedList, but a single linked list. That slows down removing the last element. So: an unsuited data sructure also for the original code. Use my solution with a **`LinkedList`** if you still have the code around.

Comment: There is no element removal in the problem (Kattis Teque) - only pushing into front, back and middle, and element retrieval. Should I try a solution with two data structures being array deques?

Answer (score 1):

A modification of Joop Eggen's solution would be to use 2 arrays (front array for fast pushFront, back array for fast pushBack).

- frontIndex = anything in between front.length / 2 and front.length - 1
- frontMidIndex = frontIndex - 1
- backIndex = anything in between 0 and back.length / 2
- backMidIndex = backIndex + 1

Effective contents: front[frontIndex .. frontMidIndex[ + back[backMidIndex .. backIndex[

pushFront:

- frontIndex > 0?

  - set at frontIndex, decrement frontIndex
- else frontMidIndex < front.length

  - shift front array back by x, increment frontIndex and frontMidIndex by x, set like above
- else

  - either copy some part to back or grow array and then proceed like above

pushBack:

- the same for back, backIndex (< back.length), backMidIndex (> 0), switching in/decrement and the shift direction

pushMid (this needs some more thinking):

- Optimum would be that the effective length of front and back are equal or off by one. 
  Then this becomes a set at frontMidIndex or backMidIndex (simular logic to above)
- If the mid falls in the middle of the valid range of one of the two arrays, you can

  - move contents in this array to create the place for the element.
  - or move contents between the two arrays to adjust the midIndexes for further pushMid.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the numbers in your solution? How do they work? why is frontIndex "anything"?

Comment: The actual value to use depends on the relation between front/back pushes and mid pushes. Choosing the number involves a trade off of making the one or the other slower.

Comment: Ah. Hang on, in your "effective contents" do you mean **frontMidIndex]** and **backIndex]**? and is frontMidIndex supposed to be **frontLength - 1**? If so, then I can understand this much more easily!

Comment: In "effective contents" I really meant *frontMidIndex[*. That means exclusive ;) That way frontMidIndex kann be frontLength.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late to answer your question but a hint to those who are struggling with this kattis problem;

From my understanding of operations among array(list,queue,stack...), it is always difficult to save time in adding/deleting elements while still having O(1) time complexity to access random indexed elements if we only use array-like obejcts.Thus, I used hashmap to reach O(1) complexity of adding and accessing in this kattis problem. Plus Joop Eggen's idea, the problem can be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).